# ORDER BY is not working with the session

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get the latest record from the table session_details therefore I used ORDER BY ... DESC but the output isn't coming. i have user a session inorder to get the value from the login itself.

```
    <head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../includes/logout.php"> logout mofo </a><br>

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

echo $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM session_details  WHERE student_id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ORDER BY 'session_id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Session ID:" . $row["session_id"] . "<br>";
    echo "ID: " . $row["student_id"] ."<br>";
    echo "Student Name: " . $row["student_name"]. "<br>";
    echo "Lecturer Name: " . $row["supervisor_name"]. "<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your PHP Error log. Thatwill give you a huge clue.

Comment: Clue: session_start() should be done first before anything is sent t the output buffer

Comment: `ORDER BY 'session_id` - error @RiggsFolly edit

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` should be done first before anything is sent t the output buffer. It does not need to be inside a test, just start the session in every script that needs it before doing anything else.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
?>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../includes/logout.php"> logout mofo </a><br>

<?php
include_once('../includes/connection.php');

echo $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM session_details  
        WHERE student_id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' 
        ORDER BY session_id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Session ID:" . $row["session_id"] . "<br>";
    echo "ID: " . $row["student_id"] ."<br>";
    echo "Student Name: " . $row["student_name"]. "<br>";
    echo "Lecturer Name: " . $row["supervisor_name"]. "<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You should really be using parameterized bound queries to protect you against SQl Injection as well

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
?>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../includes/logout.php"> logout mofo </a><br>

<?php
include_once('../includes/connection.php');

echo $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM session_details  
        WHERE student_id = ?
        ORDER BY `session_id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$result = $stmt->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Session ID:" . $row["session_id"] . "<br>";
    echo "ID: " . $row["student_id"] ."<br>";
    echo "Student Name: " . $row["student_name"]. "<br>";
    echo "Lecturer Name: " . $row["supervisor_name"]. "<br>";

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"It does not need to be inside a tes"* - what's a "tes"?

Comment: sort of like those Italian Innocenti cars; little beauts as they are.

Comment: [Didn't see my ping?...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699974/order-by-is-not-working-with-the-session#comment74444995_43699974)

Comment: you also messed up your `'" . $_SESSION['id'] . "` in that edit.

Comment: welcome, that kick was originally for the OP. I edited/pinged you when I saw the answer you popped in ;-)

Comment: I saw that but your `while/else` has no `if` and an extra brace. That tea must be pretty strong today lol

Comment: I think I will go watch tele instead, for my own safety! @Fred-ii-

Comment: I'd say *Cheers* is appropriate then ;-) Looks good to *moi*.